# cluster not working with cdh4 tarball installation

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am trying with installing CDH4 using tarball version , but facing issues as in steps taken by me are as below :

i downloaded tarball from link `https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/CDH4+Downloadable+Tarballs`

i first untar the hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-0.20.2+1341 tar file

i did with configuration changes in

```
hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-0.20.2+1341  since i wanted mrv1 not yarn .
```

the first thing as per mentioned in cdh4 installation was to configure HDFS

i made the relevant changes in

```
core-site.xml
hdfs-site.xml
mapred-site.xml
masters --- which is my namenode
slaves ---- my datanodes
```

copied the hadoop configurations on all the nodes in the cluster

did a namenode format .

after format i had to start the cluster , but in the bin folder could not

find start-all.sh script . so in that case i started with command

```
bin/start-mapred.sh
```

in the logs it shows jobtracker started and tasktracker started on slave nodes
but when i do a jps

i can see only

```
jobtracker
jps
```

further going did a datanode start on the datanode with below command

```
bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode .
```

it shows datanode started .

Namenode not getting started , tasktracker not getting started .

when i checked with my logs i could see

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.io.FileNotFoundException: webapps/hdfs not found in CLASSPATH
```

not sure what is stopping my cluster to work .

earlier i had a cdh3 running . so i stopped the cdh3 cluster . Then i started with installing cdh4 . Also i changed all the directories hdfs-site.xml i.e. pointed it new empty directories for namenode and datanode and not the used the ones defined in cdh3.

but still nothing seems to help .

Also i turned off firewall since i do have a root access but same thing it did not work for me .

Any help on above will be great help.

---

thank you for kind reply but

I do not have

```
start-dfs.sh file in bin folder
```

only files in /home/hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0/bin folder are as

```
start-mapred.sh
stop-mapred.sh
hadoop-daemon.sh
hadoop-daemons.sh
hadoop-config.sh
rcc
slaves.sh
hadoop
```

command now i am using are as below

for starting datanode :

```
for x in /home/hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0/bin/hadoop-* ; do $x start datanode ; done ;
```

for starting namenode :

```
bin/start-mapred.sh
```

still i am working on the same issue .

Answer (score 1):

Hi sorry for the above misunderstanding the following commands can be run to start your datanodes and namenode

To start namenode:

```
hadoop-daemon.sh  start namenode
```

To start datanode:

```
hadoop-daemons.sh  start datanode
```

To start secondarynamenode:

```
hadoop-daemons.sh --hosts masters start secondarynamenode
```

Answer (score -1):

The **jobtracker** demon will get started in your master node and **tasktraker** demons will get started in each of your datanodes after you run the command

```
bin/start-mapred.sh
```

In **Hadoop Cluster Setup** only **jobtacker** demon will be show  by JPS command in masternode and in each of your datanodes you can see **Tasktracker** demons runnig by using JPS command.

Then you have to start HDFS by running the following command in your masternode

```
bin/start-dfs.sh
```

This command will start **namenode** demon in you namenode machine (in this configuration your masternode itself I believe) and **Datanode** demons are started in each of your slave nodes.

Now you can run JPS on each of your datanodes and it will give output

```
tasktracker
datanode
jps
```

I think this link will be usefull
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/